# Definition essential supremum

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider the following fragment from Axler's "Measure, Integration & Real analysis":

[image]

Is the definition of $\Vert f \Vert_\infty$ unaffected when we change any of the strict inequalities into non-strict inequalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu \{x:|f(x)| >t\}=0$ then $\mu \{x:|f(x)| \geq t+\epsilon\}=0$ for any $\epsilon >0$ and it follow from this that the infima are the same whether you have greater than or greater than or equal to in the definition.

Comment: And the $t > 0$ vs $t \geq 0?$

Comment: Also, is the infinum a minimum?

Comment: No, the infimum need not be a minimum.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that $>$ cannot be changed to $\ge$ in both places. It is fine to use $\ge$ in both places, and the quantity $||f||_\infty$ does not change if one makes that change.

Comment: @SheldonAxler You are right. That was a mistake.